# What is the standard for writing tests for a play framework module?

Tags: playframework

How do I write tests for a play framework module I am creating?  I created the module using play new-module myModule but could not find anything in the generated scripts to create or run tests.  What is the standard way that people write tests for play modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the same path as the examples that come with play itself:

```
your-module
|- samples-and-tests
   |- demoapp
      |- test
         |- ApplicationTest.java
         |- BasicTest.java
```

Also look inside the Scala module, it uses the same approach and has one app called `just-test-cases`.